# When switching tabs in ext.net - the split-button keeps adding additional menu items after each load

Tags: ext.net, split-button

Using ext.net, the split-button control will add multiple menu items after each reload.  I can't seem to figure out how to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

When copying controls into Visual Studio, the IDE will always add auto generated ID's.  This causes issues sometimes, remove the auto generated ID's and this should fix the issue.